# How to make jquery use ID instead of CLASS?

Tags: jquery

I have read that it is better performance to have jquery use a DIV's ID instead of a CLASS  This code below uses a div class instead of ID, can you make it use the ID instead?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  $(".flash").fadeOut("slow", function () {
  $(".flash").remove();
      }); }, 2000);
 });
</script>
<div class="flash" id="flash">tessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssst</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#flash').fadeOut...
```

The [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) are good at explaining this.

It is just like in CSS:

> '#' for id.
>
> '.' for class

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash (`#`) instead of a dot (`.`) :

```
$("#flash").fadeOut("slow", function () {
$("#flash").remove();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use $(function(){}); as a shorcut to $(document).ready(function(){});
Yes you can use (#) insted of (.). Also you need not require to write $("#flash") again inside  below code snippet

```
    $("#flash").fadeOut("slow", function()
    {
        $("#flash").remove();
    });
```

you can write

```
    $("#flash").fadeOut("slow", function()
    {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

ie you can do with *this* keyword

Try this example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("#flash").fadeOut("slow", function()
            {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="flash" id="flash">tessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssst</div>

</body>

</html>
```